# How to create own package by copying files from existing packages

Tags: android

I tried to create a own package using the .java files from different packages. The package is successfully created but if i try to send use sendTextMessage from my package its shows error but If i use this function from android.telephony package then the program successfully execute. Please suggest how to use the  function from my own package.

Comment: Can you give an example what you try to do? I don't understand what you wrote.

Comment: Actually I tried to change few codes in SmsManager.java file in android,telephony package , but I couln't since few packages are not public , so I created a package in my own package where I copied all the necessary files. Now I tried to send a message from my project using the SendTextMessage() function from my own package but its showing some errors;

Comment: That will probably not work. You can create a copy of functionality and use your own version (if you use your own package name, compare support `Fragment` vs native implementation) but you can't replace code that exists in the system. Android will ignore classes that already exist (in some optimization step during installation).

Comment: Can you help how to solve this problem, I need to make some changes in the SmsManager file in Android.telephony for my project .The class file exist in Android.telephony package in eclipse sdk

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifically import your package like below

```
    import my.package.SmsManager;
```

Comment: I did but Its still not working, There is no error in the code but when I try to send the message in the project the abnormally terminate.

Comment: 04-10 05:23:11.781: E/AndroidRuntime(928): at    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) This Error is coming in the program

Comment: can you paste your code snippet so that we can see whats the issue?

Comment: SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(phno, null, "hello This is LUNA Project", null, null);
     
        Here if I use import android.telephony ; then the function is working properly but if I import my own package then its showing error.